# How to implement live word count for UITableViewCell TextView object?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitextview

On another view I have this function (below) that does a live word count on a TextView object based upon the given conditions then displays it on a label. I would like to do the same for my TableView Cells. However, this function clearly won't work since it requires the 'savedHashtagTextView' (textView) and 'hashtagCount'(label) fields from the cell its going to count from. I'm not sure exactly how to make this work. Please help - I've been stuck on this for hours!

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        let components = savedHashtagTextView.text.components(separatedBy: "#")
        hashtagCount.text = String(components.count)
        if hashtagCount.text == "0" {
            hashtagCount.text = ""
        }
}
```

Comment: Sorry if I don't full understand your approach, but aren't you able to pass the same data to the tableview cell as you did for your textview? maybe post some code of your cell object and tableview.

Comment: No worries, I was having a hard time explaining it. I edited my problem above and removed unnecessary information. However, to answer your question, this function doesn't know which cell's 'savedHashtagTextView' it's going to read from and which 'hashtagCount' label it's going to modify. Thus, my problem is figuring out how to design this function such that it does what it's supposed to do but also knows which cell It's modifying. I hope that helps!

Comment: Okay, I see, you're counting words from each cell and feeding that count to a label which could be in the same viewcontroller. I'm sure the answer made is very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to create a custom `UITableViewCell` object with the `UITextViewDelegate` protocol so you can get the word count for the specific `UITableViewCell` `UITextView`. Furthermore, you will want to somehow send the word count to the `ViewController` so you can update the word count `UILabel`. You can achieve this by creating your own `CustomCellDelegate` protocol which requires a `updateWordCount()` function and then use this protocol in your `ViewController`.

When the word count is updated you will now want to call the `updateWordCount()` function which will be located in your `ViewController` utilizing the `CustomCellDelegate` protocol.

As an example here is what you will want to do:

Create a CustomCell.swift file as follows:

```
// Create the protocol
protocol CustomCellDelegate {
    func updateWordCount(count: Int)
}

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell, UITextViewDelegate {
    // Your UITextView
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
    // The cells delegate -- which we will set to self when initiated
    var delegate: CustomCellDelegate?

    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
         // Get the word count here
         let wordCount = 10
         // Now we call the delegate to send the wordCount to the ViewController
         delegate?.updateWordCount(count: wordCount)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        textView.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Now create the Custom Cell in your storyboard and use the `CustomCell` class for it along with setting its `identifier` to "CustomCell". Also, make sure you link your `UITextView` to the outlet in the `CustomCell` class.

Now in the `ViewController` which contains the `UITableView`:

```
// Use the CustomCellDelegate protocol here
class YourViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, CustomCellDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var wordCountLabel: UILabel!
    // This is the function required by the CustomCellDelegate
    func updateWordCount(count: Int) {
        wordCountLabel.text = "Word Count: \(count)"
    }

    // Set up the custom Cell
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        // Setup the delegate
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }
}
```

Warning: This code is untested and I wrote it all out on StackOverflow. There may be syntax errors but aside from a few potential syntax errors this will work.

**Edit:**

Based on your comment the word count label is in the cell. This means we no longer need the `CustomCellDelegate` protocol and can make some minor changes to make this work.

CustomCell.swift:

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell, UITextViewDelegate {
    // Your UITextView
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
    // Your Label
    @IBOutlet weak var yourLabel: UILabel!

    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
         // Get the word count here
         let wordCount = 10
         // Change the wordCount labels text
         yourLabel.text = "Word Count: \(wordCount)"
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        textView.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Make sure you utilize both the outlets in the `CustomCell`.

Your `ViewController`:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    // Set up the custom Cell
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to make such a detailed answer! Your code would work perfectly assuming that the word count label wasn't in the custom cell. However, in my case, it is. Thus, trying to link the label to the view controller gives me the error: "Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content". Any suggestions?

Comment: @MansurAhmed I updated the answer (check the bottom portion of it underneath EDIT). The only difference is you no longer need the CustomCellDelegate protocol and the labels outlet will be inside the CustomCell. Please let me know if you are still having trouble getting it to work. :)

Comment: I adopted your new code but even that didn't do anything. I added a print statement in the textviewDidChange function to see if it's even called but it's not. Furthermore, I added 'cell.savedHashtagTextView.target(forAction: #selector(HashtagCell.textViewDidChange(_:)), withSender: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)' in the cell creation function to see if that would help but even that doesn't. Any more suggestions? :(

Comment: I have other objects such as buttons in the custom cell in which i use protocols and delegates to work and they're perfectly fine, it's just the label that's proving to be so difficult. I have other textView functions that handle some auto type functionalities but i placed those in the ViewController file and they work fine as well. This just has me horribly stumped.

Comment: @MansurAhmed In my code I originally forgot to set the `UITextView` delegate to self. I just updated it (look at the change I made to the `CustomCell` `awakeFromNib()` override). If you add that it should work now. Please let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: @MansurAhmed I just tested it and it is working for me. Could you edit your question and add some snippets of your custom cells code so I could take a look?

Comment: IT WORKED! I had a copy of textView.delegate  in the cell creation function for a previous application, but after removing it, IT WORKED! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!

Comment: @MansurAhmed Glad to hear you got it working :) Best of luck with the rest of your apps development!